# Tutorials on Using Mixpanel in an MVC app

Tags: model-view-controller, mixpanel

I am using content security policy in a web app and so the MixPanel JavaScript library that using inline script sadly just won't work for me. Before I invest time figuring out how to use the Java Lib I wonder if anyone has done it and has a tutorial they can point me to or advice / examples? Google is sadly not my friend tonight....

Answer (score 0):

Following should solve the problem as long as browser support [async javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_async.asp) load. [I have tested it with only Mixpanel 2.2]

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var b = window.mixpanel || [];
if (!b.__SV) {
    var i, g;
    window.mixpanel = b;
    b._i = [];
    b.init = function (a, e, d) {
        function f(b, h) {
            var a = h.split(".");
            2 == a.length && (b = b[a[0]], h = a[1]);
            b[h] = function () {
                b.push([h].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0)))
            }
        }
        var c = b;
        "undefined" !==
        typeof d ? c = b[d] = [] : d = "mixpanel";
        c.people = c.people || [];
        c.toString = function (b) {
            var a = "mixpanel";
            "mixpanel" !== d && (a += "." + d);
            b || (a += " (stub)");
            return a
        };
        c.people.toString = function () {
            return c.toString(1) + ".people (stub)"
        };
        i = "disable track track_pageview track_links track_forms register register_once alias unregister identify name_tag set_config people.set people.set_once people.increment people.append people.track_charge people.clear_charges people.delete_user".split(" ");
        for (g = 0; g < i.length; g++)
            f(c, i[g]);
        b._i.push([a, e, d])
    };
    b.__SV = 1.2
}
b.init("YOUR TOKEN");
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2.2.min.js" async="true"></script>
```

replace "YOUR TOKEN" with your mixpanel toekn.